# Angular cli, cannot execute command npm install

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular-cli

i have strange problem, i can build and run command `npm install` on linux machine but when i try to run in on windows 10 OS i have error log is below

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\puszka\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install' ]
2 info using npm@5.5.1
3 info using node@v8.8.0
4 verbose npm-session c88843dd32c85215
5 silly install runPreinstallTopLevelLifecycles
6 silly preinstall angular-app@0.0.0
7 info lifecycle angular-app@0.0.0~preinstall: angular-app@0.0.0
8 silly install loadCurrentTree
9 silly install readLocalPackageData
10 silly install loadIdealTree
11 silly install cloneCurrentTreeToIdealTree
12 silly install loadShrinkwrap
13 info lifecycle @angular/cdk@2.0.0-beta.10-f375f92~prepack: @angular/cdk@2.0.0-beta.10-f375f92
14 error cb() never called!
15 error This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
16 error <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

i checked and confirmed if i have any files under path `C:\Users\puszka\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\git-clone-56cb57f2\angular\cdk.es5.js` i don't have any files there but npm creates folder named `@angular` and no `angular` so if there were path like this `C:\Users\puszka\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\git-clone-56cb57f2\@angular\cdk.es5.js` everything would be perfect but i don't know how to do this.

Comment: I would downgrade your npm version. There are a lot of issues with npm 5. Notice line 15: `This is an error with npm itself.` 
  This is not an Angular issue.  https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16991

Comment: I did downgrade, npm is 5.2.1 and node 8.2 but when i try to `ng serve` it says that cdk and other packages are bit installed

Comment: So install them.

Comment: I installed it but npm says that it dont see those packages

Answer (score 0):

As far I understand your problem,

```
1)Check node --version installed or install it.
2)Install npm install -g @angular/cli and check ng --version.
3)Check npm --version.

Then after creating project run `npm install`.
```

You can try by uninstalling if installed earlier and then install again.

Refer:https://github.com/angular/angular-cli